# AStar Implementation Not Working

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I've been trying to get my aStar algorithm working for a few days now without success. It is built around a grid which each tile represents a "Location" object. That class contains X and Y values on the grid. I can move in all directions, diagonal and horizontal/vertical. The list which aStar returns for me is always empty. Here is all the relevant code.

Comment: Did you try setting breakpoints inside your aStar function to check what is going on?

Comment: what is `openList` and `closedList` (`cloestList`), typo for `openSet`, `closedSet`?

Comment: Yes, edited. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your `start` Node, you don't assign it a `parent`:

```
// current start node
Node current = new Node(start, null, 0, getDistance(start, finish));
```

Therefore, this loops never starts even one iteration:

```
while( current.parent != null ) {
    path.add( current );
    current = current.parent;
}
```

Leaving `path` empty.

Comment: What should I initialize as the start node for the parent then? I thought the parent is supposed to be the node which you got there from. That's not the case for the start node.

Comment: But you don't have any other nodes initialized and `openSet` includes only this first node. So what should happen?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice your code continues after the `return` statement. But the compiler didn't see it either. You should add another `return` by the end of `aStar`

Comment: What do you mean? I clearly add to the open set at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @BruceHansworth But what happens after you add? The method is finished, the scope closes - and everything is deleted. You **must** `return` something. To be exact, a `List<Node>`

Comment: Oh sorry. I'm returning null then ( if no path could be created ). I only return path whenever I can actually construct it.

Comment: But you never check if a path was constructed, so you never return either null or the found path.

Comment: I do. Read my code. I check if the current node that is being evaluated is the final point I want to get to. Then I loop through the parent nodes and create my path.

Comment: @BruceHansworth you've added a `return null` statement without checking if there's any found path

Comment: That's because a path only exist if we are at the final node. Then I construct the path. If we never get to the final node because isValid() returns false for every neighboring node ( we are blocked in ), then obviously there won't be a path and there is a null return statement.

Comment: @BruceHansworth I suggest you put some breakpoints in your code and run it in Debug mode.

Comment: I have. The loop literally runs forever and returns nothing. I can never hit the breakpoint by the return path statement ( or the return null ). The grid is too big to step through the entire thing.

Comment: @BruceHansworth  in that case "returns for me is always empty" from the question is not very correct... it should be "... never returns"... probably as misleading as the posted code. Hint: what happens if there is no way from start to end (finish, ...)